# Load files from one git repository to another?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Scenario is we have an application repository for the devs to use, and a configuration repo with some config files for maintainers to use.

At the moment, we just copy/paste the file in and set up a gitignore because we don't want to track it as part of the main branch.

Just want to know if there's a smarter way of handling this (aside from having it all in the same repo).  I did consider linking the file, but that would have issues when we come to deployment/build server.  The other option was adding a build step to fetch the file automatically.

I'm sure there's a better way of doing it than any of the things I've mentioned above, but not sure what it might be.  And google-fu is failing me.

Comment: If these things have different development lifecycles and maintainers, a separate repository (or potentially multiple separate repositories) make more sense. Branches are supposed to represent different states of a common set of files, not to track completely independent files.

Comment: I'm personally a fan of having a separate repo with a build step to fetch the file automatically. It's clean, easy to understand, and easy to maintain. If it's automated, you don't have to worry about people forgetting to run that fetch step.

Comment: Apologies, I did mean repository.  I'll update the question